# update data extension with query activity

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, dataextensions

I'm trying to create a query activity to get who opened any email yesterday and update it to a data extension on Exact Target. I'm using the following code

```
SELECT 
 SubscriberID as SubscriberKey,
 case when DATEPART(HOUR, EventDate) BETWEEN 0 AND 6 then '6'
 when DATEPART(HOUR, EventDate) BETWEEN 6 and 12 then '12'
 when DATEPART(HOUR, EventDate) BETWEEN 12 and 18 then '18'
 when DATEPART(HOUR, EventDate) BETWEEN 18 and 24 then '24'
 end open0_L
FROM _Open 
WHERE 1=1
and EventDate >= DATEADD (day, -1, GETDATE())
```

But, I'm getting errors on the last line with the update method. If I remove this line:

```
and EventDate >= DATEADD (day, -1, GETDATE())
```

It works for update. How can I fix this?

**EDIT**
These are the fields on the target data extension:

```
SubscriberKey Text (Primary Key)
EmailAddress  EmailAddress
open0_L       Number
open1_L       Number
open2_L       Number
open3_L       Number
open4_L       Number
open5_L       Number
open6_L       Number
open7_L       Number
open8_L       Number
open9_L       Number
open10_L       Number
```

EDIT2

I edited the query, to get only distinct subscriberID, but still get error.

```
SELECT 
     distinct SubscriberID as SubscriberKey,
     case when DATEPART(HOUR, EventDate) BETWEEN 0 AND 6 then '6'
     when DATEPART(HOUR, EventDate) BETWEEN 6 and 12 then '12'
     when DATEPART(HOUR, EventDate) BETWEEN 12 and 18 then '18'
     when DATEPART(HOUR, EventDate) BETWEEN 18 and 24 then '24'
     end open0_L
    FROM _Open 
    WHERE 
EventDate >= DATEADD (day, -1, GETDATE())
```

EDIT3
I'm removing the time part of Event date now. But till get errors.

```
SELECT 
     distinct SubscriberID as SubscriberKey,
     case when DATEPART(HOUR, EventDate) BETWEEN 0 AND 6 then '6'
     when DATEPART(HOUR, EventDate) BETWEEN 6 and 12 then '12'
     when DATEPART(HOUR, EventDate) BETWEEN 12 and 18 then '18'
     when DATEPART(HOUR, EventDate) BETWEEN 18 and 24 then '24'
     end open0_L
    FROM _Open 
    WHERE 1=1
    and CONVERT(date, EventDate) >= DATEADD (day, -1, GETDATE())
```

Comment: What error?  At validation or runtime?

Comment: What's columns are in the target data extension?  What is the primary key on the target data extension?

Comment: @AdamSpriggs I updated the question with the fields on the target data extension. The error is on runtime. I don't see a message of the error. I'm running the query on Automation Studio. Where can I see the error message?

Answer (score 2):

There's no need for the `1=1` in your query:

```
SELECT 
 SubscriberID as SubscriberKey,
 case when DATEPART(HOUR, EventDate) BETWEEN 0 AND 6 then '6'
 when DATEPART(HOUR, EventDate) BETWEEN 6 and 12 then '12'
 when DATEPART(HOUR, EventDate) BETWEEN 12 and 18 then '18'
 when DATEPART(HOUR, EventDate) BETWEEN 18 and 24 then '24'
 end open0_L
FROM _Open 
WHERE EventDate >= DATEADD (day, -1, GETDATE())
```

You're assigning `open0_L` as `Text`, but storing it as a `Number`.  That could potentially cause a runtime error.

Second, you didn't mention what the Primary Keys were on your Data Extension.  You could be violating it since `_Open` can return multiple rows for a given subscriber.  I'd expect you'd want `SubscriberKey` + `EventDate` as the Primary Key to accommodate your results.

SFMC Support can give you details about query failures -- as can certain SFMC Partners with access to the Error Log.

Comment: I edited the question with the PrimaryKey and I also edited my query with a distinct on the primarykey, but I'm still getting errors

Comment: Just setting a PK on SK isn't enough.  You'll need another field, since a subscriber have `_Open` records multiple times on a single day.  You'll also need to match data types and precision in your target data extension with the [_Open schema](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/data_view_open/).

Comment: But i just want to check if he opened yesterday or not. I don't need to know if how many times he opened

Comment: Then you'll need to collapse it down in your query.  `EventDate` is date + time.

Comment: I tried to do this on EDIT 3. But still getting errors

Comment: Have the query target a new data extension with no primary key and you will see what Adam is referring to.  You results will most likely contain multiple entries for a single subscriber.

Answer (score 0):

This is a SOQL query in Apex, correct? Would this suit your needs?

```
and EventDate >= LAST_N_DAYS:1
```

or

```
and EventDate >= YESTERDAY
```

Alternatively, since you're probably making this query in Apex and you may want exact timing instead of including the entire day, you could add a variable in your code before the query:

```
DateTime last24hours = System.now().addHours(-24);
```

and then your query's where clause would include:

```
and EventDate >= :last24hours
```

Comment: no, it's on query activity. I don't know if it's on Apex. YESTERDAY is not defined. And on ther other options that you mentioned, I get syntax error.

Comment: Gotcha. I mistook your query for SOQL. My solution won't work for this, and unfortunately I'm not familiar enough with ExactTarget/AMPscript to assist here.